# How to append text into File when using Filelock acquire Function Python?

Tags: python

I'm locking a file using filelock Lib in Python. There is some function called **acquire**, I'm using that for locking perspective.

```
import filelock as fl
lock = 'test.txt'
lock1 = fl.FileLock(lock)

with lock1.acquire(timeout=10):
    x = open(lock,'a+');
    print(x.write("Hello World"))
    lock1.release();
    x.close()
```

I have opened a file(appending mode) in **with** block. But when i'm executing above code, text is not appending into file specifically into **with** block. Instead of appending text, it is overwriting like in **write** mode.

Can someone help me in this case?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when using filelock you should use the file name and add a suffix of ".lock"

from filelock [readme](https://pypi.org/project/filelock/):

> Don't use a FileLock to lock the file you want to write to, instead create a separate .lock file as shown above.

```
import filelock as fl
lock = 'test.txt'
lock1 = fl.FileLock(lock + '.lock')

with lock1.acquire(timeout=10):
    x = open(lock, 'a+')
    print(x.write("Hello World"))
    lock1.release()
    x.close()
```

and in another syntax using context manager:

```
from filelock import FileLock
file_name = 'test.txt'
lock_name = file_name + '.lock'

with FileLock(lock_name):
    with open(file_name, 'a+') as f:
        f.write('Hello World')
```

Comment: Thanks @michal Yanko. One quick question...which one is best practice...release the lock and close the file or close the file and release the lock.is it possible to release the lock after closing the file? is it a right way of doing? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should first close the file and then release the lock. Only when you close the file you can know for sure all the data was flushed to the file. If you release the lock before closing the file other process can access the file and it can create a race condition.

Comment: Hi @Michal Yanko - One quick question.. I have done the same file locking concept in Linux box. I see .lock file is not deleting after closing the file. Can you please tell me why is this happening ?

Comment: @premRexx In Unix operating system the lock file isn't deleted - check out this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368159/why-flock-doesnt-clean-the-lock-file
You can use a SoftLock instead which only checks for the existence of a lock file but according to the filelock documentation:  `The SoftFileLock only watches the existence of the lock file. This makes it ultra portable, but also more prone to dead locks if the application crashes. Youcan simply delete the lock file in such cases.`